# Rindler Observers

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, observers

In the process of transition from STR to GR, I'm trying to understand what Rindler observers actually are. Here is how one of the questions from our assignment defines them:

> If the distance between B and A as measured in their common MCRF is some constant $\xi$ they are called Rindler observers.

Doesn't this statement simply point the obvious? In their common MCRF, both A and B are at rest, so the distance between them is constant. Does it have something to do with the fact that their common MCRF is also changing with time? But shouldn't the common MCRF *not* exist at all instants of time? Because for a common MCRF to exist, they must have the same velocity, which is not true at all the instants of time.

I do not understand how this definition can be useful for deriving the trajectory of particle B, given that of A as $$x_A=\dfrac{c^2}{a}\,\cosh\left(\dfrac{a\tau}{c}\right)$$ and $$ct_A=\dfrac{c^2}{a}\,\sinh\left(\dfrac{a\tau}{c}\right).$$

It would be appreciated if someone could explain what Rindler observers actually are, and the distance between them in what exact frame remains constant in terms of A and B as the two required observers.

Our prof mentioned something about how we cannot solve this problem like the way we do for a single accelerated observer, and we have to actually transition to an accelerated frame of reference. I've not understood this exactly either, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A [Rindler observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) is one who's wordline is $(ct_A,x_A)\,.$ Any other observer $B$ that rests in $A$'s reference frame has trivially a constant spacial distance $\xi$ to $A$. You can read in the link that they both rest in an accelerated frame of reference. I have no idea why you think we cannot solve this problem (which problem BTW ?) like the way we do for a single accelerated observer. Are you sure you understood your prof correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by the worldline being $(ct_A, x_A)$? And what is this accelerated frame of reference in which they both are at rest? Isn't this frame defined for one instant only? And they can have constant acceleration in their MCRFs only, right?

Comment: I have the impression that you should study from scratch the Wikipedia article to which I gave the link. Forget about two observers. A single Rindler observer $A$ is sufficient. This observer rests in an accelerated frame (also known as a rocket) and feels constant proper acceleration that is physical and can be measured with an accelerometer. This proper acceleration is known as inertial force from Newtonian mechanics.